# Is it practical to glue stuff to tiles with hot glue?

Tags: tile, adhesive

I need to hang several small things in the shower (like a soap holder). The shower cabin has tiles. To do this, I am thinking to use a hot glue gun.

I've seen it used before to glue small plastic things in the shower, though I am not sure of the practicality of it.

Is this the recommended way? Will this type of glue last? Or should I use some other type of glue?

Edit : thanks for the answers! If I could accept them both, I would - since joining both anwsers give me comprehensive information about what to do in both cases - when I want to glue  small and light plastic stuff, and when I want to attach something heavier like holder bar.

Comment: I know this is late, but in case anyone's googling around: Definitely go the silicon route. I was trying for ages with a regular hot glue gun and it just would not stick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, a silicone based glue would adhere fairly well to most tiles. On smooth tiles it can be removed with a razor blade. On rougher tiles, a blade and a wire brush can get it off.  The tiles need to be thoroughly cleaned before using (as with any glue).

This is not as strong a bond as epoxy or construction adhesive, as suggested by Chris Cudmore, but is more easily reversed if necessary.

Because it is not as strong, I would limit it to lighter items, like the soap holder you describe. It is definitely not suitable for a grab bar or other attachment that needs certain hold. Safety items need to be attached to structure, not glued on.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a two part epoxy for a permanent install.  The only way you're getting it off is to chip away the underlying tile.

Construction adhesive such as PL400 would also work.  It's used to glue concrete pavers together when building a wall. However, it can become brittle over time and break off.

If your attachments are ceramic as well, then the proper way to do it is to chip out a tile, and install the attachment using the same tile adhesive used to install the tiles.  Usually you can buy things like a soap dish sized properly for such an installation.